# How to insert summary report as last page in main report?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal reports using in asp.net web application. I've a main crystal report(.rpt) file which is having header, Group header sections, sections and footer.

Depends upon the datatable data, sections will be filled.
Now i need to display summary of whole records which should be placed at the end page of main report.

How can i achieve? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put summary of your desired field in section `report footer`.

If you need count of all records then do formula field and write `count (any field)` and put it also in section `report footer`.

If you need summary of more fields then its best to put new subreport in section `report footer` and then do summaries inside subreport.